# A Taylor Series with a Cantor Set as its Convergent Set on the Unit Circle

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

Herzog and Piranian proved that for every $F_\sigma$ set M in the complex unit circle (the boundary of the unit disc), there exists a complex power series $P(z)$ whose set of convergent points is precisely $B_1(0)\cup M$. Now imagine stretching the ternary Cantor set by $2\pi$ and wrapping it around the unit circle. This set is closed and thus is $F_\sigma.$ Does anyone know of a series P with such a set as its M? Or I suppose more generally, with any Cantor set as its M?

Comment: Perhaps build it using the Poisson kernel, integrating the "fractal" measure on that Cantor set

Comment: @GEdgar I'd never heard of the Poisson kernel before, I'm looking into it now. Thanks!

Comment: @GEdgar So after a bit of research, I think you could construct a power series with a cantor set as its set of divergent points on the boundary of the disc, but not its set of convergent points. But this is also very cool, so thank you!

Comment: @GEdgar Edit: After a bit more thought: the harmonic function you achieve through the Poisson kernel must only agree almost everywhere with the function you feed it, but any Cantor set is measure 0, so it seems the function I'm looking for would evade this method.

Comment: In place of integrand$P_r(\theta-t)f(e^{it})\;dt$, use $P_r(\theta-t)\;d \mu(t)$ where $\mu$ is the standard probability measure concentrated on the Cantor set.

Comment: @GEdgar Ah, I see. Do you think this could actually yield a practical function?

Comment: If "practical function" = "elementary function", then no.

Comment: @GEdgar of course not an elementary function, but perhaps a closed form Taylor series?

Comment: @GEdgar I seem to only be finding resources on the Poisson kernel using the standard measure on $\mathbb{C},$ do you know of a book with a more general measure-theoretic approach to the kernel?

Answer (score 0):

While the stated question seems to be too difficult (likely impossible) to find a closed form solution to, I was able to, using the advice of @GEdgar, to find a closed form Taylor series $u(z)$ which satisfies:
$$u(e^{i\theta})=\frac{1}{2}-\biggr\lvert c\left(\frac{\theta+\pi}{2\pi}\right)-\frac{1}{2}\biggr\lvert.$$
This is essentially just the function I chose so that the boundary would be continuous. The solution is:
$$u(z)=1-\frac{3}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_{\frac{\pi}{3}}^\pi\cos(n\theta)c\left(\frac{3\theta-\pi}{6\pi}\right)d\theta z^n.$$

Comment: @GEdgar Thanks for pointing me towards the Poisson kernel! After reading up, it seems like the integrating factor has to be of the form $d\mu(\theta)$ where $\mu$ is a finite measure on the unit circle, which the Cantor measure is not.